# "Filter not defined" when trying to play Tone.js sound

Tags: javascript

I am trying to recreate this example so that it plays automatically when the page is loaded: https://tonejs.github.io/docs/13.8.25/LFO

But when I put this code inside `<script></script>`in my HTML header, I get a "filter not defined" error in my console and no sound plays.

```
var lfo = new Tone.LFO("4n", 400, 4000);
lfo.connect(filter.frequency);


lfo.start();
lfo.toMaster();
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

--

EDIT

Per suggestion below, I have tried this, which removes the filter console error, but still no sound plays:

```
var filter = new Tone.Filter(200, "highpass");
var lfo = new Tone.LFO("4n", 400, 4000);
lfo.connect(filter.frequency);
lfo.start();
lfo.toMaster();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am naive to this Tone.js lib but not with browser.

This LFO is producing some kind of low-frequency oscillation according to the documentation.

```
LFO stands for low frequency oscillator. Tone.LFO produces an output signal which can be attached to an AudioParam or Tone.Signal in order to modulate that parameter with an oscillator. The LFO can also be synced to the transport to start/stop and change when the tempo changes.
```

So when following code snippet runs, please observe the browser tab, it shows a `Speaker icon` , which means browser window is playing some kind of music. So code is working fine, but the issue maybe with some kind of frequency settings

```js
var lfo = new Tone.LFO("4n", 4000, 40000);
var filter = new Tone.Filter(200, "highpass");
lfo.connect(filter.frequency);

lfo.start();
lfo.toMaster();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/14.5.41/Tone.js"></script>
```

Just run this code snippet and observe the browser tab

Or what you can do, see the following code, this is a running snippet of Tone.js this might help you!

```js
(function() {
  // Membrane Synth https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r12/MembraneSynth
  const synth = new Tone.MembraneSynth().toMaster();
  const notes = ["C3", "Eb3", null, "G3", "Bb3"];

  const synthPart = new Tone.Sequence(
    function(time, note) {
      synth.triggerAttackRelease(note, "10hz", time);
    },
    notes,
    "8n"
  );

  synthPart.start();

  /**
   * Play Controls
   */
  let playing = false;
  document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!playing) {
      Tone.Transport.start();
      playing = true;
    } else {
      Tone.Transport.stop();
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/14.5.41/Tone.js"></script>
<h1>Tone.js Note Sequence</h1>
<p>click to play</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a filter before using it. YOu can create a filter like below as per documentation shared by you:

```
var filter = new Tone.Filter(200, "highpass");
```

Comment: i updated my post - it removes the error but still no sound plays.

Comment: Tryto move your script tag at bottom of body in HTML. See its working - https://jsfiddle.net/t32xodbL/